# ios: UITableViewCell crash with custom cell in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table with two custom cells that crash when try to dequeue.

Here is the code :

```
int row = indexPath.row;

static NSString *CellIdentifier;
UITableViewCell* cell;
PoetCell * poetCell;
PoemsCell * poemsCell;

if(row == 0) {

    CellIdentifier = @"PoetCell";

} else {

    CellIdentifier = @"poemsCell";        
}

if(row == 0) {

    poetCell= [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    poetCell.image.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    if([imageData length]==0){

        poetCell.image.hidden=TRUE;
        poetCell.Name.frame=CGRectMake(124, poetCell.Name.frame.origin.y, poetCell.Name.frame.size.width, poetCell.Name.frame.size.height);

    } else {

        poetCell.Name.frame=CGRectMake(38, poetCell.Name.frame.origin.y, poetCell.Name.frame.size.width, poetCell.Name.frame.size.height);

    }

    poetCell.desc.text=pdesc;
    poetCell.Name.text=pName;

} else {

        poemsCell= [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if([poemsNames count]) {
            poemsCell.poemText.text=[poemsNames objectAtIndex:row-1];
        }
}
```

It gives error on the line :

```
poetCell= [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

which say

> [UITableViewCell setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Name.

I know this error comes when there's a bad link in the nib.. But that's not the case I believe it is in the code.. So can any one get what the problem is ?

EDITed

i think the whole problem is with the initializing of poetCell and poemsCell which is that's the code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PoetCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UILabel*Name;
    IBOutlet UILabel*desc;
    IBOutlet UIImageView*image;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel*Name;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel*desc;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView*image;

@end

#import "PoetCell.h"

@implementation PoetCell
@synthesize Name,desc,image;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

the other cell is just the same

Comment: please check this use the cell strings directl without the cellIdentifier variable.

Answer (score 0):

you might have problem in the code ! it is if the array does not have the requested index?

just make your check like this

```
    if([poemsNames count] > row  ){
        poemsCell.poemText.text=[poemsNames objectAtIndex:row-1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `poetCell.Name`. Can you make sure your custom cell has a "Name" property (in your custom cell's .h/.m) ? I think the problem comes from here.

By the way, if your custom cell does have this property, you should change it to `name` instead of `Name`. Variables with an upper case letter at the beginning is for classes names. Variables should always start with a lower case letter.

You should post your custom cell's code too.

---

EDIT :

As seen here : [Class is not key value coding-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760803/problem-with-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant)

> In interface builder you linked your IBOutlets from File's Owner when you should link them from the cell view.

Can you check that ?

Comment: Can you give us the code of your custom cell ? How can you be sure it comes from the line *poetCell= [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];* ? Can you place a breakpoint on the next line to see if you reach it ?

Comment: lol, just checking :) Can you check in your nib if there are no "dead" links ? Like an old label you may have linked then deleted ? I can't see why you'd get this error with this line..

Comment: Did you set your table view cell's class to your custom class in IB ?

Comment: And you checked "dead" links ?

Comment: i've made a whole new viewController in the storyboard and without wiring any iboutlet it gives 
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell Name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ce7280'

Comment: That's because you have to link your IBOutlets to your .h file. Set the cell's class, and link to the existing IBOutlets in your cell's .h file.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're targeting iOS5+, have you included something like the following in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:kStandardCellIdentifier bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)]
```