# Xcode bug? - this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myprogressBar.'

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, runtime-error

So I added a `UIProgressView` using Xcode's GUI feature by sliding it from the object library onto my viewcontroller calling it myprogressBar.  I then setup an `IBOutlet` variable / property for it and then synthesized it in the implementation.  Then I decided to remove everything I just added by selecting the view on the viewcontroller and pressing delete, as well as the variable, property, and synthesize statement.  The view was no longer visible in the viewcontroller and it was no longer listed under the 'view controller scene' list.  After adding some additional features I hit 'build', and it compiles and links w/o problem.  However early in the program it hits a run-time error telling me

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x1266089e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myprogressBar.'
```

I did a search for myprogressBar in my project but nothing came up.  Xcode seems to have not removed the reference to myprogressBar.

So my question:  Is this a bug or is there a way to properly remove references (which I seemed to not use) ?

Comment: make a clean. if that doesn't help restart Xcode. if that doesn't help too restart your Mac. Usually these mysterious bugs should be treated this way

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I did a clean, restarted Xcode, and restarted the Mac but still getting the same error message.

Comment: you know what? check that part of Interface Builder where you assign IBActions, you know what i mean? i forgot how it's called, cause i haven't used IB for a long time. I'm pretty sure an IBAction still hangs there

Comment: @AndreyChernukha  That did the trick.  Accessing the XML file "com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" and going to the "connections" tag there were some rogue references.  So just had to delete them and everything works now.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class is not key value coding-compliant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760803/class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone curious.  Just click on the Xcode button (seen below).  It should open up an XML (XIB) file.  Look for the `<connections>` tag where you'll find those annoying rogue references.

[image: Xcode button]

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fix this occasional problem :

1. Close the Xcode and your project.
2. Use Finder to open the folder with your Xcode project.
3. Enter the main folder, the one with your code files (not the Test folder).
4. Locate the **Base.lproj** folder and open it.
5. Right click the file **Main.storyboard** and choose Open With -> Text Edit.
6. Use the search text option to find your erroneous value (myprogressBar).
7. Erase every single line that contains the text, then save and close it.
8. Re-open your project with Xcode, clean it (menu Product) and run it.

These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just Cmd + Shift + F the Key its complaining about. It will find and show it in Xcode in Utilities area (right). Locate the key - it should already have an exclamation mark next to it. Click the 'x' next to it to delete it and you should be good to go.