# NSUnknownKeyException ios Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsunknownkeyexception

I have created a Slide drawer for my ios app.. The slide drawer working perfectly... I have a few buttons and a Textbox in the Slide drawer... The problem is whenever i try to add reference to the button/textbox which is in the slide drawer, i am getting NSUnknownKeyException... I dont know how to solve the issue, since am very new in IOs... Am including the code below...

SlideDrawer.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SlideDrawer : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *home;
- (IBAction)homeclick:(id)sender;
@end
```

SlideDrawer.m

```
#import "SlideDrawer.h"
@interface SlideDrawer ()
@end
@implementation SlideDrawer
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
 - (IBAction)homeclick:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface mainViewController : UIViewController{
UIView *menuDrawer;
}

@property (readonly, nonatomic) UISwipeGestureRecognizer     *recognizer_open, *recognizer_close;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) int menuDrawerX, menuDrawerWidth;

-(void) handleSwipes:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender;
-(void) drawerAnimation;

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
#import "mainViewController.h"

@interface mainViewController ()

@end

@implementation mainViewController

@synthesize menuDrawerWidth, menuDrawerX,recognizer_open, recognizer_close;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    menuDrawer = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SlideDrawer" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    menuDrawer.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.09 blue:0.29 alpha:1.0];
    menuDrawerWidth= self.view.frame.size.width * 0.80;
    int statusbarHeight= [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    menuDrawerX= self.view.frame.origin.x- menuDrawerWidth;
    menuDrawer.frame= CGRectMake(menuDrawerX,  menuDrawer.frame.origin.y+statusbarHeight, menuDrawerWidth, self.view.frame.size.height-statusbarHeight);
    // menuDrawer.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.09 blue:0.29 alpha:1.0];
    recognizer_close= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
    recognizer_open= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
    recognizer_close.direction= UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    recognizer_open.direction= UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_open];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_close];
    [self.view addSubview:menuDrawer];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 -(void) handleSwipes:(UIGestureRecognizer *) swipe{
     [self drawerAnimation];

}
-(void) drawerAnimation{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:-10];
    CGFloat new_x = 0;
    if(menuDrawer.frame.origin.x<self.view.frame.origin.x)
    {
        new_x= menuDrawer.frame.origin.x+menuDrawerWidth;
        UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:menuDrawer.bounds];
        menuDrawer.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        menuDrawer.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        menuDrawer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
        menuDrawer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
        menuDrawer.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer_open];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_close];
    }
    else{
        new_x= menuDrawer.frame.origin.x-menuDrawerWidth;
        UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:menuDrawer.bounds];
        menuDrawer.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        menuDrawer.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        menuDrawer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
        menuDrawer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0f;
        menuDrawer.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer_close];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_open];
    } 
    menuDrawer.frame= CGRectMake(new_x, menuDrawer.frame.origin.y, menuDrawer.frame.size.width, menuDrawer.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
 } 
 @end
```

**EDIT**

Exception is the line in main.m

```
 return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Exception

> ```
> 2015-06-10 14:07:17.357 Xpressions[5939:1056267] Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file. 2015-06-10 14:07:17.367
> ```
>
> Xpressions[5939:1056267] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key home.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0089e746 **exceptionPreprocess + 182  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00527a97 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0089e361 -[NSException raise] + 17  3   Foundation
>
>   0x001a81ee -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] +
>   282   4   Foundation                          0x00105608
>   _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115   5   Foundation                          0x0010558d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267     6
>
>   Foundation                          0x0013b016
>   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 386  7   UIKit                               0x00fa8672 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106   8
>
>   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0053d724 -[NSObject
>   performSelector:] + 62    9   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x007d647c -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 316   10  UIKit
>
>   0x00fa7133 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1775  11  UIKit
>
>   0x00fa8fd2 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions)
>   loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 180    12  Xpressions
>
>   0x000418cf -[mainViewController viewDidLoad] + 175    13  UIKit
>
>   0x00dc1da4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 771   14  UIKit
>
>   0x00dc2095 -[UIViewController view] + 35  15  UIKit
>
>   0x00cb3e85 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66   16 
>   UIKit                               0x00cb434c -[UIWindow
>   _setHidden:forced:] + 287     17  UIKit                               0x00cb4648 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49     18  UIKit
>
>   0x00cc29b6 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 80     19  Xpressions
>
>   0x00043534 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] +
>   580   20  UIKit                               0x00c56fd7
>   -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 287  21  UIKit                               0x00c57dc1 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2938   22  UIKit                               0x00c5b422 -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639   23  UIKit                               0x00c7493e __84-[UIApplication
>   _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 59  24  UIKit                               0x00c5a04a -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155   25  FrontBoardServices                  0x03200c9e __37-[FBSWorkspace
>   clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71    26  FrontBoardServices
>
>   0x0320072f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke +
>   54    27  FrontBoardServices                  0x03212d7c
>   __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 30   28  CoreFoundation                      0x007c0050
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 16  29  CoreFoundation                      0x007b5963 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195    30  CoreFoundation
>   0x007b57bb __CFRunLoopRun + 2715  31  CoreFoundation
>   0x007b4a5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443     32  CoreFoundation
>   0x007b488b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   33  UIKit
>   0x00c59a02 -[UIApplication _run] + 571    34  UIKit
>   0x00c5d106 UIApplicationMain + 1526   35  Xpressions
>   0x00043a0a main + 138     36  libdyld.dylib
>   0x02c2aac9 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

Comment: What is the exception you get? Also, add an exception breakpoint in Xcode so you can see which line causes the exception to be thrown.

Comment: Please check the editted question...

Comment: You are using xib, right?

Comment: yaa... you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for this:

Easy one, you have connection, deleted element but link between outlet and the code remained, and is now pointing to empty. This one you can check in the last tab on the right side in the interface builder.

The other one: you have connected your outlet to File owner instead to the class. Remove your outlets and connect them to the class instead. when you connect your outlets(from code to the element, you will have empty circle) you will get the popup for the selection : file owner - class.

Edit :

Remove outlets by pressing the x and then reconnect again from the code. When you remove these outlets, you will have empty circles in the .h class and reconnect again to SlideDrawer.

[image]

Comment: can you provide me a screenshot for the second solution?

Comment: well it is hard to do it with images only but it is easy to follow the steps: open SlideDrawer.xib -> go to outlets, press on filled circles to remove outlets -> open SlideDrawer.h -> you will have empty circles now -> connect them to corresponding elements -> select SlideDrawer instead of File Owner

Comment: Am sorry to say this.. But I cant find any empty cirlcles in SlideDrawer.h... :(

Comment: Have you removed the outlets from xib ? there must be at least  one for the home button if you removed them from interface builder

Comment: updated with the screenshot

Comment: I have tried as you said... unfortunately, therez no option to change from file owner to class when reconnecting... :( Its juz made the connection as before..

Comment: You have to go from code to the element, not the other way around

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80163/discussion-between-rishad-appat-and-nickcatib).

Comment: Doesnt made any change either...

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
STEP 1:Go XIB or if use STORYBOARD go STORYBOARD
STEP 2:Click View Controller
STEP 3:Again Give connection properly(Fill the circle)
STEP 4:Also check whether it is for button action or outlet property
```

**Very Important:
             Right Click the File's Owner(Yellow Color) and
             Click on the "Connection Inspector" (upper right arrow), to see all outlets at once. Look for !s which indicates a missing outlet.Remove that.
             Now it works.**

Please look the below references

1. [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)
2. [setValue:forUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793162/setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-k)
3. [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)
4. [Class is not key value coding-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760803/class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant)